# Adding Validation to Rows Dynamically Added two Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

So I have a table with two separate buttons, Edit and Deactivate. I was able to use a bind function on the deactivate and edit in order to get the button to work when I added rows. I also have validation for most of the fields. The validation works perfectly on the original rows, but does not work on any rows that are added by the user. How can I fix this?

HTML/PHP:

```
<table id="html_master">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">
</table>

<input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// ----- Deactivate Row -----

function bindDeactivate() {
  $('#html_master').on("click",".deactivate",function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
    var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
      $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
      $this.val(function(i, t) {
        return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
      });
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind the deactivate button click to the function
    bindDeactivate();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind the edit button click to the function
    bindEdit();
});

// ----- Add Row -----

function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
    element5.type = "text";
    element5.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var element6 = document.createElement("input");
    element6.type = "text";
    element6.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell6.appendChild(element6);

    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var element7 = document.createElement("input");
    var element8 = document.createElement("input");
    element7.type = "button";
    element8.type = "button";
    element7.name="edit";
    element8.name="deactivate";

    var setClass = document.createAttribute("class");
    setClass.value = "edit";
    element7.setAttributeNode(setClass);

    var setClass1 = document.createAttribute("class");
    setClass1.value = "deactivate";
    element8.setAttributeNode(setClass1);

    element7.attr="class";
    element8.attr="class";
    element7.value="Edit";
    element8.value="Deactivate";
    cell7.appendChild(element7);
    cell7.appendChild(element8);

    // Bind this new deactivate button click to the function
    $('#html_master').off("click",'.deactivate');
    bindDeactivate();

    // Bind this new deactivate button click to the function
    $('#html_master').off("click",'.edit');
    bindEdit();
}




function bindEdit() {
    $('#html_master').on("click",".edit",function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
    });
    if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
        $this.val('Save');
        tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
    } else {
        var isValid = true;
        var errors = '';
        $('#myDialogBox').empty();
        tds.each(function(){
             var type = $(this).attr('class');
             var value = $(this).text();
             switch(type){
                 case "buyer_id":
                     if(!$.isNumeric(value)){
                         isValid = false;
                         errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
                      }
                     break;
                case "poc_n":
                    if(value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case "poc_e":
                    if(value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case "poc_p":
                    if(value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";    
                    }
                    break;
             }
        })
        if(isValid){
            $this.val('Edit');              // Modifed
            tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
        }else{
            alert(errors);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Two things,  Do not mix and match old school DOM and jQuery  It will only add to confusion for yourself and other developers.  Second.  It looks like you are unbinding your delegated event when you add a row. ' $('#html_master').off("click",'.deactivate');'   This is not necessary as you are already using a delegated event

Comment: so i don't need those lines of code then?

Comment: You are attempting to delegate the event to #html_master.   when you click anywhere in the table.  your on click fires with a condition if the element being clicked has the class .deactivate.  This is how the delegated events work.  In previous version of jQuery, this was done using .delegate() and .live().

Comment: Gotcha! So how would I be able to extend the validation then into the added rows?

Comment: The binding of the original delegate that you have already does it.  You should really be using one of the browser's developer tools and debug this.